# Take screenshot of HLS video playback on Safari with Selenium and python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

When I use python and selenium to take a screenshot of an HLS video playing in Safari it does not capture the video. How is the video hidden from the screenshot?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


def timestamp():
    timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    return timestr

def main():
    browser = webdriver.Safari(executable_path = '/usr/bin/safaridriver')
    browser.get("https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8")
    time.sleep(10)
    browser.save_screenshot("artifacts/{}.png".format(timestamp()))
    time.sleep(10)
    browser.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image: This is what I see during playback when script is running.]

[image: Screenshot is blank.]

[image: Video is in the body.]

Comment: akamai uses DRM, so that's likely the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is a known issue with the Take Screenshot command in safaridriver for current shipping Safari (13.2 at time of writing) and Safari Technology Preview (Release 103 at time of writing). It also affects WebGL content.

We hope to have a fix soon. When the fix is shipped it will be mentioned in Safari Technology Preview release notes.